# Unity: Failed to capture screen shot?

Tags: unity, screenshot, error-management

I am capturing screenshots at every time step in unity using ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot. I am able to get the shots captured and saved in a certain folder but after approximately 50 timesteps the unity crashes and I get an error : Failed to capture the screen shot. Sometimes, unity crashes after 50 time-steps and sometimes after 70 time-steps, so crashing is random. 
P.S I am running my unity simulation on the guest VMware virtual machine, I have already looked into the storage and it is more than needed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not gamedev related. Unity crashing can be due to many factors, non of which are detailed.

Comment: Capturing screenshots of a game in development out of the editor sounds like a pretty normal gamedev topic to me, @Sidar. Though I think the argument could be made that Unity tech support would likely be better equipped to resolve the issue of crashes in their software. D.g, can you give us any more details of the error, or a minimal reproducible verifiable example so we can investigate this issue? Without more detail, I think logging an issue with tech support may be your best bet.

Comment: @DMGregory The questions body is too broad and could be too much of anything. The title might have `screenshot` in it but the body clearly shows it might be an entirely different problem. Therefor off topic. Could as well be a problem with VMware, drivers issues, not something we could much go on about. stackoverflow might be better suited? If OP can pinpoint to something that's related to screenshots, or his code then maybe.

Comment: @Sidar we have a distinct close reason for that: "Questions about debugging a problem must provide a minimal, complete, verifiable example of the issue..."

Comment: @DMGregory Well wasn't sure what to pick.